# working method in controller fails if same method called from class

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a function in my controller which works fine.

```
    <HttpGet> _
    <Route("SymbolExists/{symbol}", Name:="symbolexistssymbol")> _
    Function SymbolExists(ByVal symbol As String) As Boolean
        'Return SymbolHelpers.SymbolExists(symbol)
        Return symbCtx.symbols.Count(Function(e) e.Symbol1 = symbol) > 0
    End Function
```

I need this same function available in my code behind and I have a SymbolHelpers class which houses all those functions. I want to just be able to call the function from the Class in the controller but I get the error below when I do (error shown below and its the exact same code that works in the controller!!)

```
 Public Shared Function SymbolExists(ByVal symbol) As Boolean
        Using symbCtx As New SymbolsEntities()
            Return symbCtx.symbols.Count(Function(e) e.Symbol1 = symbol) > 0
        End Using
    End Function

***LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the type declaration for symbol in your second code example.

```
Public Shared Function SymbolExists(ByVal symbol as String) As Boolean
```

Without the type declaration the compiler seems to default to an Object to Object comparision which LINQ to Entities cannot translate.

Comment: tired eyes i guess, should've caught that